# Mobilepush save contact attribute using SDK

Tags: mobile

I am integrating your mobilepush SDK with iOS. Push notificatios are working fine and thebasic integration is working OK. Now i need to register an email when a user opt-in for push notifications,for this i am using AddAttributeNamed:value: as follows(in bold):

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{

```
[[ETPush pushManager] configureSDKWithAppID:@"afed5da8-2ffb-4b80-8a84-e641f86f4b28"

                             andAccessToken:@"j7vqzp6p6csnvynt7w7u3byp"];

[[ETPush pushManager] setOpenDirectDelegate:self];

[[ETPush pushManager] setDisplayLocalNotificationsTo:NO];



[[ETPush pushManager] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |

                                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |

                                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

[[ETPush pushManager] resetBadgeCount];

[[ETPush pushManager] applicationLaunchedWithOptions:launchOptions];

...

...

}

...

...

...

// Called when the device receives a token from Apple.

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

  [[ETPush pushManager] registerDeviceToken:deviceToken];

  [[ETPush pushManager] addAttributeNamed:@"ClientEmail" value:@"someemail@gmail.com"];

}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error

{

```
[[ETPush pushManager] applicationDidFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
```

}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo

{

```
NSLog(@"Received a push! %d", application.applicationState);
```

}

i have created "ClientEmail" contact attribute following this steps http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/mobilepush/contacts/#ContactAttributes

but the ClientEmail atttibute is never set. Any ideas how can i set "ClientEmail" using your mobilePush SDK?

Regards,

M